# Lebesgue and Riemann integrals two proofs

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

1.

Let *X* be a finite closed interval [*a,b*] in ***R***, let ***X*** be the collection of Borel sets in *X* and let λ be a Lebesgue measure on ***X***.
If *f* is a nonnegative function on *X*, show that
*∫* *fdu* =∫a->b *f*(x)*dx*

I know that the right side denotes the Riemann integral of the function. 
and I am given the hint that first establish this equality for a nonnegative step function (a linear combo of characteristic function of intervals.)

2.

A slight change, let *X*=[0, +∞) let ***X*** be the Borel subsets of *X* let λ be a Lebesgue measure on ***X***.
If *f* is a nonnegative function on *X*, show that 
*∫* *fdλ* =lim b ->+∞ ∫0->b *f*(x)*dx*

It means that the Lebesgue and the improper Riemann integrals coincide. But how to show

*∫* *fdλ* =lim b ->+∞ ∫0->b *f*(x)*dx*

Please help prove the two similar questions in details.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(1) If $f : X= [c,d] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a nonnegative Riemann integrable function, then

$$\int_c^d f(x) \, dx  = \sup_{\phi  \leqslant f} \int_c^d\phi(x) \, dx = \inf_{\psi  \geqslant f} \int_c^d\psi(x) \, dx ,$$

where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are step functions.  This is straightforward to show using upper and lower Darboux sums and integrals.

Since any step function is a simple function, we have for simple functions $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{\psi}$

$$\sup_{\phi  \leqslant f} \int_c^d\phi(x) \, dx \leqslant \sup_{\hat{\phi}  \leqslant f} \int_{[c,d]}\hat{\phi} \leqslant \inf_{\hat{\psi}  \geqslant f} \int_{[c,d]}\hat{\psi}  \leqslant \inf_{\psi  \geqslant f} \int_c^d\psi(x) \, dx ,$$

and Riemann integrability implies Lebesgue integrability with

$$\int_{[c,d]}f= \int_c^df(x) \, dx .$$

The converse is not true.  Lebesgue integrability does not imply Riemann integrability -- even on a finite interval. (Consider the Dirichlet function).

(2)  Note that by the monotone convergence theorem, if $f$ is nonnegative and is improperly Riemann integrable, then

$$\int_{[a,\infty)}f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[a,\infty)} f 1_{[0,n]} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^n f(x) \, dx = \int_a^{\infty} f(x) \, dx$$

since the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals coincide on bounded intervals.

Comment: Do you know how to solve part 2? Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is just monotone convergence theorem -- I'll add above.